# Safe way to allow user generated expressions against SQL columns

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am allowing users to generate expressions against predefined columns on the table. A user can create columns, tables, and can define constraints such as unique and not null columns. I also want to allow them to generate "Calculated columns". I am aware that PostgreSQL does not allow calculated columns so to get around that I'll use expressions like this:

```
SELECT CarPrice, TaxRate, CarPrice + (CarPrice * TaxRate) AS FullPrice FROM CarMSRP
```

The user can enter something like this

```
{{CarPrice}} + ({{CarPrice}} * {{TaxRate}})
```

Then it gets translated to

```
CarPrice + (CarPrice * TaxRate)
```

Not sure if this is vulnerable to sql injection. If so, how would I make this secure?

Comment: Why not just let them create views? Views can have calculated columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just take user input as desribed above and substitute in select column list. If so, that is sure not safe, because something like:

```
"* from SomeSystemTable--({{CarPrice}} + ({{CarPrice}} * {{TaxRate}})"
```

Will allow user to select anything from any other tables he has permissions for. You can try to build expression tree to avoid that: parse user input into some structure describing variables and arithmetic operations between them (like parsing arithmetic expressions). Otherwise you can remove all {{}} from your string (ensure that any {{}} corresponds to a column in a table) and check if only "+-*()" and whitespace characters left.

Note that from user experience viewpoint you will need to parse expression anyway, to warn user about errors without actually running the query.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you utilize STORED PROCEDURES to conduct this?

This way, you can, for instance, define variables to receive what user wrote and check if there are some BLACKLISTED words (like DELETE, TRUNCATE, ALL, *, and so forth).

I don't know PostgreSQL, but if it's not possible there, you can also check those problematic commands BEFORE translate them to call your SELECT statement.

Comment: Assuming it's an option for PostgreSQL (I don't know), this is definitely the right option. Not only is it safer, but you don't need to recompile when you change SPs